# Handling time-series data efficiently in Firebird

Tags: sql, performance, time-series, firebird

We have a couple apps that have the classic problem with time-series data: we need to store per-minute time-series data (timestamp, device/channel ID and one or more columns of device data), purge that data based on age, and retrieve 2-day blocks (2880 data points) of the data for graphed display - I need every discrete data point in the time range, not a sum or other calculated value, in order to plot the graph.  Retention is 36 months, so the FDBs can get pretty big.  While I'm aware of the various time-series databases available, for now I'm locked into Firebird - changing to some other DB is *not* an option.

Because the inserts are per-minute, keeping up with the inflow of data is no problem.  Purging likewise isn't a big problem (a thread runs every day at a defined time to age out old data.)  But retrieval of those 2-day blocks is a killer as the DB grows.  I've tried some different things (storing the timestamp as separate date and time integer fields rather than a single timestamp field, juggling rowset size, etc.) to speed up retrieval, but nothing helps much.

I'm looking for some help with tuning and best-practices for this on Firebird: Are there specific things (schema design, query layout, etc.) that can significantly improve speed in a time-sequence scenario?

Comment: What is the current structure, and which indexes do you have? Also, which Firebird version are you using?

Comment: Also consider posting some example data, and queries you currently use. It is very hard to give a too the point answer on such a broad question.

Comment: There were schemes like calculating intermediate aggregates, so your if your request would be (in arbitrary units) from 15 to 67 you would take ready aggregates for 20,30,40,50 and only do per-query summing for "tails" 15-20 and 59-67

Comment: Using Firebird 2.5, .FDB on the same local drive as the program and server.  Currently the timestamp is stored as two columns, an integer for date and an integer for time, with an index on the date - this seems to give the best performance, though only marginally.  Also tried a single timestamp column, both with and without an index. Typical query is 'select * from "OPCHist" where WDATE in (119678, 119679);' though I've tried versions with a 'between' clause and 'WDATE = 119678 or WDATE = 119679' type of clause. I've also tried juggling rowset size.

Comment: I should add: All server params are at defaults, including page size.

Comment: Edit your question with details, please don't add information through comments, that makes it hard to read and unclear for other readers.

Comment: `select *` ? why on Earth??? do you really need ALL the rows and ALL the columns? won't something like `Select sum(field1), avg(field2) from...` suffice?

Comment: Yes, I do need all the columns, within the specified date range, because I'm graphically plotting the data points by time. In the example case, there's only 4 columns: ID, date and time fields, and the data point. In the one device table that has multiple (34) data points per row, I tailor the select clause to just the columns I need as I'm probably plotting only a few of the points from each row.

Comment: well, then make some statistics over how many queries with how long dates range you usually do. Then think how often you would do intermediate aggregates to some already pre-summed shards mostly, except for starting and ending pieces of the range.